# How do I test a WSGI application from a script?

Tags: python, django, testing, wsgi

I'm debugging a really weird problem with a mod_wsgi-deployed application resulting in Django/Apache (not yet known which) giving status 500 errors to some users instead of the correct 404. I want to exclude Apache from the debugging environment to determine which part of the setup is at fault and send my requests manually to the WSGI handler.

I suspect it's as easy as setting the environment and running `python wsgi_handler.py`, but is this correct? What should the enviroment contain additionally? Any pointers to existing documentation?

Comment: Where are your Django unit tests?  Are you using the Django unit test framework?

Comment: @S.Lott: it's an application I've inherited, no code of mine is yet in it. It has no unit tests as of now and I can't reproduce the problem on any of the test boxes, only the one in production has this problem :(

Comment: Sounds like the time to start writing unit tests.  Just focus on this one area and no others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it's as easy as setting the environment and running python wsgi_handler.py,

Correct.

> What should the enviroment contain additionally? Any pointers to existing documentation?

Did you read this? http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html

You can easily run a web server from your desktop for testing.  It's a very few lines of code.

http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html#wsgiref.simple_server.make_server